# WebApi Odata string parameters - how to get rid of the ' for functions?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am a little lost here.

Given the following method:

[ODataRoute("MktInstrument(Symbol={symbol})")]
 public MktInstrument MktInstrument(string symbol) {

I call it using a URL in the form of:

http://localhost/MktInstrument(Symbol='FOREX!EURxUSD')

That is nice - but the variable symbol now includes the ' that wrap the parameter.

if I put that into the template

[ODataRoute("MktInstrument(Symbol='{symbol}')")]

I get an error that the template is not valid.

If I call it witout the warapping

http://localhost/MktInstrument(Symbol=FOREX!EURxUSD)

then the method is not called. Am I really supposed to remove the '' around the string parameter myself or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can make the action method like "public IHttpActionResult Function([FromODataUri]string symbol)" which means you add attribute [FromODataUri], it will not have single quotes. You can refer to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support, the related statement is 
‘[FromODataUri]’ is mandatory for complex, entity and all collection. However, it is optional for Primitive & Enum. But for string primitive type, the value will contain single quotes without ‘[FromODataUri]’.

Comment: Thanks. Overlooked that one ;)